# Find the number of $7$-tuples such that all elements are distinct and $x_{i}∈ ℤ_{≥0}$. Such that $x_{1}+x_{2}+x_{3}+......+x_{7}=36$

Tags: combinatorics, summation, permutations

Find the number of $7$-tuples $(x_{1},x_{2},x_{3}......,x_{7})$ such that all elements are distinct and $x_{i}∈ ℤ_{≥0}$.

Such that

$x_{1}+x_{2}+x_{3}+......+x_{7}=36$

My trial:

This is similar to the condition that $x_{i}<x_{i+1}$ with the only difference that I'll have to multiply my answer by $7!$

Then I assume:

$x_{1}=a_{1}$  and $x_{i+1}=x_{i}+1+a_{i+1}$,

where $a_{i}∈ ℤ_{≥0}$

Leaving me with:

$7a_{1}+6a_{2}+5a_{3}+.....+a_{7}=15$

Then I can't seem to proceed.

For example: ($3$-tuples)

$x_{1}+x_{2}+x_{3}=6$

the possible $3$-tuples are:

1)$(0,1,5),(0,5,1),(1,5,0),(1,0,5),(5,1,0),(5,0,1)$

2)$(0,2,4),(0,4,2),(2,4,0),(2,0,4),(4,2,0),(4,0,2)$

3)$(1,2,3),(1,3,2),(2,3,1),(2,1,3),(3,1,2),(3,2,1)$

the total $3-tuples$ are $(3)(3!)=18$

what I say is that assuming that $x_{i}<x_{i+1}$ gives me only three cases:

$(0,1,5),(0,2,4),(1,2,3)$

and finding this is sufficient for solving the question because the final answer would be achieved if I multiply this by $(3!)$. (i.e. answer$=3(3!)=18$)

Comment: You're just brute-forcing your 3-tuple example? Why not brute force the 7-tuple example? My result of brute force was $(21+110)7!$  where 21 is the number of length 7 partitions of 36 and 110 is the number of length 6 partitions of 36. I could list them all if you wanted :)

Comment: If you are familiar with partition functions, the answer can be found at http://oeis.org/A026813

Comment: As noted in the comments above the number you are looking for is related to the number of partitions of a number which is not a 'nice' function. If you know about generating functions you can procced from $7a^1+6a^2+5a3+.....+a^7=15$ by noting that your problem is equivalent to finding the coefficient of $x^{15}$ of $F(x)=(1+x^7+x^{14}+...)(1+x^6+x^{12}+...)...(1+x+...x^{15}+...)=\prod_{i=1}^7\frac{1}{1-x^i}$. This can be calculated as $a_{15}=\frac{1}{15!}F^{(15)}(0)$.

Comment: @ Μάρκος Καραμέρης  I tried this method also. but i could'nt find a way to calculate the coefficient of $x^{15}$